# eclipse workspace creation from git

Tags: eclipse, git, github, workspace

What I am trying to do, is write a script to make a new eclipse workspace.

I have a list of git repository, and I want to make a new workspace that has a project for each repository.

any ideas?

Comment: Nice idea. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What is your specific question?

Comment: You can do this and more with Eclipse Oomph: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer#Tutorials

Comment: I tried a few thinks mainly along the lines of :- eclipse -data <workspace> -application <app> -import <url> the problem is trying to work out want the app is I need to use

Comment: I don't know much about Eclipse but it could be worth investigating to see if Eclipse has command line options. I think you'd want to use Eclipse to make the workspace so that it works in later versions too. Just a suggestion.